# Angular How to invoke pipe from string with name of pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 2 how can I use reflection (or whatever I would call it, here) to use a pipe? I have a string with the name of the pipe (like "lowercase") and I want to invoke the pipe using only that string.

For example:

JSON

```
var cols = [{ dataProperty: "city", pipeName: "lowercase"},{ dataProperty: "state", pipeName: "uppercase"}]
var rows = [{city: 'Walla Walla', state: 'wa'}];
```

HTML (Angular component excerpt)

```
{{ rowData[col.dataProperty] | this.[col.pipeName] }}
```

But this code didn't work.

What do I use instead of `this.[col.pipeName]` to give me the equivalent of dynamically calling `uppercase` or `lowercase` (or whatever pipe I define in `pipeName`, assuming it is a pipe my code can access)?

Comment: I think inject custom pipes in component and apply them in a function is easier to achieve and much cleaner on your data themselves

Comment: I wondered that too.. one thought was to instead use an actual component with `*ngSwitch` instead of pipe, but if using pipes maybe something like `cellFormatPipe:col.pipeName` is better? `cellFormatPipe` being a big fat switch statement in a single pipe instead of creating separate, purpose-driven pipes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### If your json data is going to be hardcoded

```
var cols = [{dataProperty: "city",  pipe: new LowerCasePipe()},
            {dataProperty: "state", pipe: new UpperCasePipe()}]
```

Then in your template html

```
{{col.pipe.transform(rowData[col.dataProperty])}}
```

all default angular pipes implement the [PipeTransform](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/change_detection/pipe_transform.ts) interface, which has the **transform** method on it.

---

### If your data will come from an api

You could leave it as `pipeName: "uppercase"`
and pull the corresponding pipe out of a dictionary.

```
export class PipeManager {
  private static _pipes = {
    'upperCase': new UpperCasePipe(),
    'lowerCase': new LowerCasePipe(),
    'currency': new CurrencyPipe('en')
  };

  public static PipeForKey(key: string) {
    return PipeManager._pipes[key];
  }
}
```

Then in your template html

```
{{PipeManager.PipeForKey(col.pipeName).transform(rowData[col.dataProperty])}}
```

This solution could be cleaned up a bit but, hopefully you get the idea.